# can't connect to my sql while executing playbooks of openstack

Tags: centos7, openstack

i already executed first two playbook successfully but while i am trying to execute setup_openstack.yml that is third playbook , it is showing this error:

PLAY [Prepare MQ/DB services] ************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Ensure Rabbitmq vhost] *************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 14 March 2019  11:20:34 +0530 (0:00:00.087)       0:00:00.087 ********
ok: [centos-infra_keystone_container-******* -> ip of container]

TASK [Ensure rabbitmq user] **************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 14 March 2019  11:20:36 +0530 (0:00:01.765)       0:00:01.852 ********
ok: [centos-infra keystone_container-*******-> ip of container]

TASK [Ensure Rabbitmq vhost] *************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 14 March 2019  11:20:38 +0530 (0:00:02.215)       0:00:04.067 ********

TASK [Ensure rabbitmq user] **************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 14 March 2019  11:20:38 +0530 (0:00:00.028)       0:00:04.095 ********

TASK [Create DB for service] *************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 14 March 2019  11:20:38 +0530 (0:00:00.031)       0:00:04.127 ********
**fatal: [centos-infra_keystone_container-******-> ip of container]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'ip of lb\' (113 \"No route to host\")')"}**

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *********************************************************

Comment: ip of lb is reachable from infra host .. i checked using ping

Comment: ip of container is pinging from infra but not login through ssh

Comment: If you grep your ansible directory for "ip of lb" you need to replace this with an actual ip address or dns.